# Validating model sent to Web API controller

Tags: c#, validation, asp.net-web-api

In a call to Web  API service I have following class properties that I need to send to its controller method:

```
public class FindBookingRequestModel 
{
    public string ReservationNumber { get; set; }
    public string CreditCardNumber { get; set; }
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
    public string Origin { get; set; }
    public string Destination { get; set; }
    public DateTime? StartDate { get; set; }
}
```

Per use case, I have three scenarios where I need to validate model sent to web api controller and to assure that folowing class properties are populated, othervise I need to throw BadRequest exception.

1. use case:

   ```
   {
       "ReservationNumber": "WERTSDFFSDF",
       "CreditCardNumber" : "3333"
   }
   ```
2. use case

   ```
   {
       "ReservationNumber" : "WERTSDFFSDF",
       "EmailAddress" : "somene@gmail",
       "Origin" : "FRA",
       "Destination" : "MUN"
   }
   ```
3. use case

   ```
   {
       "StartDate" : "2015-12-15",
       "EmailAddress" : "somene@gmail",
       "Origin" : "FRA",
       "Destination" : "MUN"
   }
   ```

So it should be an error if we send this model to controller:

```
{
    "ReservationNumber": "WERTSDFFSDF",
    "Origin" : "FRA",
}
```

or this one:

```
{
    "EmailAddress" : "somene@gmail",
     "StartDate" : "2015-12-15",
}
```

What is the most efficient way to ensure that fields are passed as stated in use cases above?

Comment: You can write your custom attributes and do Model Validation in ASP.Net WebApi - http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/model-validation-in-aspnet-web-api

Comment: Thanks, but I need validation of class instance - whether particular call fits into use cases or not.

Comment: My first thought was to have separate objects with the required properties, but there's no such thing as overloading a Web API method based on the parameter provided. The use cases are supposed to have at least those parameters and not more, correct?

Comment: Can your use cases be separated on client side, e.g. by having different input forms? Then you could address different controller methods for every use case which would make validation a lot cleaner on the server side.

Comment: @rdoubleui The thing is here to obtain only one class - we are not allowed to make three diferent view models to fit into use case neither we want to make three separate methods on controller instead of one

Comment: Then this needs to be done on the server side indeed, as Trevor suggested. Just leads to long if statements, don't see any more efficient way. My point was, in order to create the object variations for those three use cases you are constraining the objects on the client side anyway (in order to make the below validation work, you must ensure that the remaining parameters are not given (that is `null`) - they are not optional as I understand).

Answer (score 0):

You can implement [IValidatableObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.ivalidatableobject(v=vs.110).aspx) to perform cross property validation, it is probably also worth considering the individual property value validation too.

I'd suggest using Regular expressions where possible for property values (they will only be run if the property value is not null since you don't have any required fields for all valid types, avoid the `[Required]` attribute) and then use the `Validate` method for cross property validation:

```
public class FindBookingRequestModel : IValidatableObject
{
    [RegularExpression("[A-Z]+")]
    public string ReservationNumber { get; set; }

    [RegularExpression("...")] // Find a regex online
    public string CreditCardNumber { get; set; }

    [RegularExpression("...")] // Find a regex online
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }

    [RegularExpression("[A-Z]{3}")]
    public string Origin { get; set; }

    [RegularExpression("[A-Z]{3}")]
    public string Destination { get; set; }

    public DateTime? StartDate { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(this.ReservationNumber) 
            && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(this.Origin))
        {
            yield return new ValidationResult(
                "You cannot search using Reservation Number and Origin", 
                new[] { "ReservationNumber", "Origin" });
        }

        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(this.EmailAddress) 
            && this.StartDate != null)
        {
            yield return new ValidationResult(
                "You cannot search using Email Address and Start Date", 
                new[] { "EmailAddress", "StartDate" });
        }

        yield break;
    }
}
```

If there are too many invalid combinations, you could do something like this instead:

```
    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(this.ReservationNumber) 
            && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(this.CreditCardNumber)
            && this.EmailAddress == null
            && this.Origin == null
            && this.Destination == null
            && this.StartDate == null)
        {
            // OK - Only reservation number and credit card number specified
            yield break;
        }

        /// ...

        yield return new ValidationResult(
            "Invalid combination of search terms");
    }
```

Comment: Isn't that approach coming from the wrong side? There are "endless" combinations of invalid parameters. One should find an elegant way to filter for positives.

Comment: You could flip that on its head and return a single validation result if none of the 3 valid ones match - I'm showing how to validate across properties in a way supported by the validation used in WebApi - I'm not proposing to write all the validation rules for the OP.